# device admin's wipeData(0) does not format SDCard. How to wipe SDCard clean using device admin or other way programatically?

Tags: android

I want to remotely reset phone to default factory settings. I used DeviceAdmin's wipeData(). Does the job but doesnt clean the SDCard.

Any clue what am I doing wrong OR is it that wipeData() does not clean the SDCard data. If so, how can I do it programatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal

```
String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
```

With the String of the external store (mostly "/sdcard") u can use java.io.file to create a new file using this path. With this, u can get all the childs and use recursion to delete everything.

Comment: but is there no inbuilt api/function to do this? I thought it would have been a native android functionality just like devi admin's lockNow() or wipeData()?

Answer (score 1):

You can use wipeData(DevicePolicyManager.WIPE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)  rather than manually deleting contents of SD Card.

Comment: Just a short note on this: my Galaxy Tab 10.1N (Android 3.2) doesn't work with this option (fails while unmounting: `doUnmountVolume ... OperationFailedInternalError`)

Comment: Yes there is issue on some devices and google is working to fix it. See limitations of SD Card wipe section on https://support.google.com/a/answer/173390?hl=en and mostly those issues are on Samsung devices.

Comment: Thanks for the note, VishalKale. Actually, there is no SD card slot in the Galaxy Tab 10.1N and its memory is not partitioned, so there is no external storage that could be unmounted. Probably the reason for the error ... ;)